# I'm writing code for word puzzle game and can't figure out how to include line of text into loop

Tags: python, string, function, loops, methods

I'm writing code for word puzzle game and trying to add line "The answer so far is " before "_ _ _ _ _" like in the output image below

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmB2l.png)

```
import random
import re
```

display instructions

```
infile = open('wp_instructions.txt', 'r')
line = infile.readline()
while line:
    print(line.strip())                 #prints line
    line = infile.readline()            #loops the iteration
infile.close()    
words = ['apple', 'banana', 'watermelon', 'kiwi', 'pineapple', 'mango']
word = random.choice(words)

symbol = "_"                             
blanklines = len(word) * symbol
status = "The answer so far is "
print(status, end=" ") 

guesses = ''
```

any number of turns can be used here

```
turns = 4


while turns > 0:
```

counts the number of times a user fails

```
failed = 0
```

all characters from the input.
word taking one at a time.

for char in word:

```
    # comparing that character with
    # the character in guesses
    if char in guesses: 
        print(char, end= ' ')

    else:
                  
        print("_", end= ' ')
        
        # for every failure 1 will be
        # incremented in failure
        failed += 1


if failed == 0:
    # user will win the game if failure is 0
    # and 'You Win' will be given as output
    print("Good job! You found the word", word + '!') 
    endgame_button = input('Press enter to end the game.')
    if endgame_button == '':        
        break

# if user has input the wrong alphabet then
# it will ask user to enter another alphabet
guess = input("\nGuess a letter (" + str(turns) + " " + "guesses remaining): ")

# every input character will be stored in guesses 
guesses += guess 

# check input with the character in word
if guess not in word:

    turns -= 1

    
    if turns == 0:
        print('Not quite, the correct word was ' + str(word)+ '. Better luck next time')
        endgame_button = input('Press enter to end the game.')
        if endgame_button == '':
                break
```

Comment: Not clear what do you need.. try to minimize your question or explain it better (my suggestion with shorter descriptions)

Comment: @adirabargil I edited it and hope it makes sense now